# Vue v-model binding form Checkbox to Boolean variable is passing an Event object instead of true/false

Tags: vue.js, vue-component

I´m using a Vue base component which wraps a simple check box. In my template Im doing a 2-way bind using a v-model to a Boolean variable in my data. Nothing too fancy but there´s a problem with my implementation where instead of the target variable receiving a `true/false` value when the control state is turned `on/off` (check/unchecked), it receives an `event object`. I don't know what I'm doing wrong, any ideas?

I see this exception in the console when I click the control:

> [Vue warn]: Invalid prop: type check failed for prop "value". Expected
> Boolean, got Event

found in

```html
  <BaseSwitch> at src/components/BaseSwitch.vue
       <Card> at src/components/Card.vue
         <SlideYUpTransition>
           <Modal> at src/components/Modal.vue
             <RFQSales> at src/views/rfq/RFQSales.vue
               <FadeTransition>
                 <App> at src/App.vue
                   <Root>
```

base-switch component:

```html
<template>
    <label class="custom-toggle">
        <input type="checkbox"
               v-model="model"
               v-bind="$attrs"
               v-on="$listeners">
        <span class="custom-toggle-slider rounded-circle"></span>
    </label>
</template>
<script>
export default {
  name: "base-switch",
  inheritAttrs: false,
  props: {
    value: {
      type: Boolean,
      default: false,
      description: "Switch value"
    }
  },
  computed: {
    model: {
      get() {
        return this.value;
      },
      set(value) {
        this.$emit("base-switch", value);
      }
    }
  }
};
</script>
<style>
</style>
```

Template:

```html
<base-switch class="pull-right" v-model="modals.modalNewRFQ.data.borrowButton"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't stated the version of Vue you use. Is it **Vue2** or **Vue3**?

Your  tag is also not fully copy/pasted. I have changed it to

```
 <base-switch class="pull-right" v-model="borrowButton" @base-switch="process($event)"></base-switch>
```

Now your code works perfectly with **Vue3**.

Here is the link to the working playground:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue-f3nqz1?file=src/App.vue

For Vue3 you must define the emitted events, to make it work well.

```
emits: ['base-switch'],
```

Also, pay attention to passing value:

this.$emit("base-switch", **value**);

and

@base-switch="process(**$event**)">

If your function gets an Even Object, then you can try `JSON.stringify()` it to check the properties. Possibly, it is related to your `$listeners` solution. I couldn't guess it to reproduce the problem.

Here is the code:

**App.vue**

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <base-switch class="pull-right" v-model="borrowButton" @base-switch="process($event)"></base-switch> <br />
     Value: {{value}}
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import BaseSwitch from './components/BaseSwitch.vue'

export default {
  name: 'App',
  components: {
    BaseSwitch
  },
  data() {
    return {
      borrowButton: false,
      value: null
    }
  },
  methods: {
    process(value) {
      this.value = value;
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

**BaseSwitch.vue**

```
<template>
    <label class="custom-toggle">
        <input type="checkbox"
               v-model="model"
               v-bind="$attrs"
               >
        <span class="custom-toggle-slider rounded-circle"></span>
    </label>
</template>
<script>
export default {
  name: "base-switch",
  inheritAttrs: false,
  emits: ['base-switch'],
  props: {
    value: {
      type: Boolean,
      default: false,
      description: "Switch value"
    }
  },
  computed: {
    model: {
      get() {
        return this.value;
      },
      set(value) {
        this.$emit("base-switch", value);
      }
    }
  }
};
</script>
<style>
</style>
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. I am using Vue2 at the moment which seems to bear into the problem. Your suggestion to stringify the event should help me at least get this to work. Cheers